# scheduled cloud function error: Function returned undefined, expected promise or value

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a scheduled cloud function which updates a document field with a value from an api call. However I get the error mentioned above in the logs, altought I'm returning a promise (as far as I know)

Any help is appretiated

the api call returns this json:

```
{ "alarm": "false" }
```

My Code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as rp from 'request-promise';

admin.initializeApp()

export const scheduledAlarmUpdate = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 30 minutes').onRun((context) => {

    const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('alarms').doc('stuttgart');
    const username = 'bitfactory';
    const pass = '...';

    const options = {
        url: 'https://api.bitfactory.io/fineparticlesalarm/',
        auth: {
            user: username,
            password: pass
        },
        method: 'GET',
        json: true
    }

    return rp(options).then(data => {
        console.log(data.alarm)

        docRef.set({
            alarm: data.alarm
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise returned by the `set()` method, as follows:

```
export const scheduledAlarmUpdate = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('every 30 minutes')
  .onRun(context => {
    const docRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('alarms')
      .doc('stuttgart');
    const username = 'bitfactory';
    const pass = '...';

    const options = {
      url: 'https://api.bitfactory.io/fineparticlesalarm/',
      auth: {
        user: username,
        password: pass
      },
      method: 'GET',
      json: true
    };

    return rp(options)
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.alarm);

        return docRef.set({  // ->>> here return
          alarm: data.alarm
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```